# How do I assign uncategorized category to a post after deleting it original category

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many, blogs, updating

Am working on a laravel blog project whereby If I delete a category, I want all posts of this category moved to 'Uncategorized' Category. if post belongs the deleted category and other categories also then avoid moving that post to uncategorized else move the post to uncategorized.
I am using many to many relationship for Category-Post Model. see my code below:

**Post migration i have**

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->foreignId('user_id')
    ->constrained()
    ->onDelete('cascade');

    $table->string('title')->unique();
    $table->string('featured_image')->nullable()->default('default_featured_image.jpg');
    $table->text('detail');
    $table->string('tags')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Category migration**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('detail',300)->nullable();
        $table->string('image')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**Pivot migration for the relationship**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('category_post', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedInteger('post_id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('category_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**Post Model**

```
 function categories(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
 }
```

**Category Model**

```
function posts(){
   return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class);
}
```

**Category Controller**

```
public function destroy(Request $request)
{
   $cat_id = $request->category_id;
   $category = Category::find($cat_id);

   $posts_to_update_category_id = $category->posts()->wherePivot('category_id','=',$cat_id)->get();
   foreach($posts_to_update_category_id as $post){
       $post = Post::find($post->id);
       $post->categories()->sync(1); //uncategorized id = 1
   }
   

   $category->delete();
   return redirect('admin/category')->with('success', ''.$category->title.' has been Deleted');
}
```

my problem with the code is that it end up updating all post with the deleted category id to 1(uncategorized). meaning if i have 1 post with two different categories say cat1 and cat2 and i delete cat1, i dont expect this post to be moved to uncategorized but my code does move it and also remove the cat2 from it making it just uncategorized. please help if you can. thanks

Comment: why make a category called `uncategorized`, just set it that when it has no category, it is uncategorized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$category->posts()->wherePivot('category_id','=',$cat_id)->get();` already returns the posts instances, so you dont have to do `$post = Post::find($post->id);` later

You can verify if it has more than one category, that means that this post shouldn't be moved to uncategorized, but just removed the category right?

So you can do this

```
public function destroy(Request $request)
{
   $cat_id = $request->category_id;
   $category = Category::find($cat_id);

   $posts = $category->posts()->with('categories')->wherePivot('category_id','=',$cat_id)->get();
   foreach($posts as $post){
       if (count($post->categories) > 1) {
           $post->categories()->detach($cat_id);
       } else {
           $post->categories()->sync(1); //uncategorized id = 1
       }
   }
   

   $category->delete();
   return redirect('admin/category')->with('success', ''.$category->title.' has been Deleted');
}
```

Comment: @Richie glad it worked, if you can, mark my answer as correct so others with the same problem can see what worked for you

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution would be to delete the relation when the category is deleted

**Pivot migration for the relationship**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('category_post', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedInteger('post_id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('category_id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreignId('category_id')
            ->constrained(categories)
            ->onUpdate('cascade')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreignId('post_id')
            ->constrained(posts)
            ->onUpdate('cascade')
            ->onDelete('cascade');

    });
}
```

When you delete either the post or the categor, the relation is gonna get deleted by cascade automaticaly in the database

Comment: @Richie if the answer helped you, please set it as "the right answer" so your question will be marqued as "concluded"